# Book or Tale identification - Building is in fact a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

Can anyone please remind me the name of a Sci-Fi tale that a man lives in a strange building and can't get out. He starts to search other strange things.

I can't really remember the story, but I know that in the end the building turns out to be a spaceship and flies away.

Comment: Do you have any more details; format (*was* it a book?), age (at the very least how recently did you read it?), etc.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

["Shipshape Home"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56264) by [Richard Matheson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Matheson), originally published in the [July 1952 *Galaxy*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58539), which you can read at the [Internet Archive](http://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1952-07/Galaxy_1952_07#page/n85/mode/2up).

The story starts with Ruth, the narrator's wife, complaining that the janitor gives her "the creeps":

> Her eyes narrowed. "You listen to me," she said. "That man has some design in being here. He's no janitor. I wouldn't be surprised if . . .
>
> "If this apartment house were just a front for a gambling establishment. A hideout for public enemies one through fifteen. An abortion mill. A counterfeiter's lair. A murderer's rendezvous."

Ruth finds the engines in the basement and shows them to her husband:

> I felt a little detached from reality. East 7th Street, I told myself again. An apartment house on East 7th Street. It's all real.
>
> I couldn't quite convince myself.
>
> We stopped at the bottom. And I just stared. Engines, all right. Fantastic engines. And, as I looked at them it came to me what kind of engines they were. I'd read about science too, the non-fiction kind.

They find themselves locked in their apartment. They try to get away:

> "The engines!" Ruth suddenly cried. "They're starting them!"
>
> "They have to warm up!" I made a wild guess. "We can still get out!"
>
> I let go of Ruth and grabbed a chair. For some reason I felt that the windows had been automatically locked too.
>
> I hurled the other chair through the glass. The vibrations were getting worse.
>
> "Quick!" I shouted over the noise. "Out the fire escape! Maybe we can make it!"

The ending:

> And then the sky, which was growing light, grew dark. My head snapped around. Women were screaming their lungs out in terror. I looked in all directions.
>
> Solid walls were blotting out the sky.
>
> "Oh my God," Ruth said. "We can't get out. *It's the whole block.*"
>
> Then the rockets started.